# Custom animations for Twitter Bootstraps tab function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations

I'm using this function for a tab/nav system:

```
# http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})
```

However, I'd like to use custom CSS animations. Is this possible? I know there's a "fade" function but I can't find much documentation on this function.

Any help, greatly appreciated!

Alex

Comment: really? a simple google for me brought up these resources: http://fvsch.com/code/transition-fade/test5.html http://hugoware.net/blog/using-css-transitions http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/

Comment: I suppose I should have been a tad clearer. I want to use jQuery css animations with the functionality of twitter bootstrap "tab" plugin...?

Answer (score 2):

Add "fade" to the class attribute of the div's with the class "tab-pane"
And additionally "in" to the active tab.

```
<div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="tab1">
 ...
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
 ...
</div>
```

Other animations:

```
$('.tabs').tabs()
    .bind('change', function (e) {
        $(this).next().hide().<<Add code to show >>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'slideDown' or 'fadeIn'. Basic jquery effects should apply just as 'show' does.

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/